# Vue js $vm0 is not defined

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Can someone help real quick. I'm trying to test something with `Vue` instance in console, but in console when I write `$vm0` or `$vm0.$children`

`Uncaught ReferenceError: $vm0 is not definedat :1:1`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This only works if you have vue dev tools installed. Make sure you select the component first. It should look something like this:

[image]

Then you can inspect it in the console tab of chrome dev tools.

Comment: How do you access the <Root> without Vue devtools then?

Comment: You cannot, AFAIK.

Comment: Hey, chris, I found a solution to this. I just did this and it worked `global.$vm0 = app;` where app is the name of my Vue instance. :) Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The question was initially asked for Vue2 I suppose, where you could use

```js
$vm0.$route.query
```

to get access to various objects on the `$vm0` Vue instance, here: router queries.

---

In Vue3, that one has changed in favor of

```js
$vm0.proxy.$route.query
```